# Is htop becoming part of the default install?

Tags: official-repositories, htop

I noticed that the `htop` package for 18.04 is in `main`, where previous releases had it in `universe`. This is reflected in [the packages index](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=htop) and [on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/htop/+publishinghistory). Software in `main` is supported by Canonical, these are usually either part of the default install (or the installer), or widely-used server software.

`htop` is pretty good, it'd be nice to have it in the default installation.

How can I find more about how and why `htop` got included in `main`?

Answer (score 9):

It seems it is not becoming part of the default desktop installation. It is, however, being included in the server image:

```
$ curl -sL http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-server/daily-live/current/bionic-live-server-amd64.manifest | grep htop
htop    2.1.0-3
```

It's now a dependency of the [`ubuntu-server`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/ubuntu-server) meta-package, so it should be installed when using the standard option in the server image, without needing an internet connection.

---

Finding more about this was a bit convoluted - there's nothing in htop's [package changelogs](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/htop/+changelog) or on the Launchpad closed bugs list, or on the `ubuntu-devel` mailing list that seemed related at a glance. Turns out, the related bug report is [#1644364 - [MIR] htop](https://bugs.launchpad.net/htop/+bug/1644364) - the `MIR` seems to be "Main Inclusion Review (or Request?)", and not the Mir display, which threw me at first.

[The MIR team](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MIRTeam) decides upon whether a package should be promoted to `main`, and the requests filed on Launchpad for such packages are usually also tagged [`[MIR]`](https://bugs.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mir). The process and criteria are described on the Ubuntu Wiki:

- [Main Inclusion Requirements](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuMainInclusionRequirements) (also see the graph of packages where dependencies are not of the required components: [component-mismatches](http://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-archive/component-mismatches.svg))
- [Main Inclusion Process](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MainInclusionProcess)

The MIR bugs offers an interesting overview of what's currently happening with the defaults. For example, it looks [MP3 support will be available by default!](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lame/+bug/1753441)

Comment: MIR being GUI type of package, it seems odd that they decided to include  a command-line utility ( and not for example a library )  like that, which is unrelated to GUI at all.

Answer (score 5):

htop is [now officially](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/u/ubuntu-meta/ubuntu-meta_1.413/changelog) in ubuntu-server as a default app!

```
ubuntu-meta (1.413) bionic; urgency=medium

  * Refreshed dependencies
  * Added gnome-bluetooth to desktop-recommends [s390x]
  * Added htop to server
  * Removed doc-base from desktop

 -- Christian Ehrhardt <christian.ehrhardt@canonical.com>  Tue, 13 Mar 2018 11:12:35 +0100
```